# mongoexport with a query does not return expected results

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoexport

im trying to use a regular expression in the query field of mongoexport so i can limit the fields that are not the test emails for running load tests with a test users, email, password, and apiKey.

I was able to use a find with

`db.users.find({email:/@company.com/},{apiKey:1,email:1}).pretty()`

and this retrieved just the records I wanted, but the following:

`mongoexport -d db_dev -c users -f apiKey,email -q "{{email:{/@company.com/}}}" --csv -o usersKeys.csv`

does not seem to work for me. Any pointers? Im using mongo2.6.3 on a mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys im a little slow today. got it now:

`mongoexport -d db_dev -c users -f apiKey,email -q "{email:/@company.com/}" --csv -o /Users/kingHenry/Desktop/usersKeys.csv
connected to: 127.0.0.1
exported 205 records`